# Merging docker containers/commits/images

Tags: docker

I have to 2 containers in which I installed 2 different sets of tools. Both containers use the same base image. Now, I like to combine both containers into one. Or alternatively, after committing these containers to images, I like to be able to merge the images. (But I would like to avoid creating Dockerfiles and merging them...)

(The sets of tools are independent, so none of the files added within one container should collide one of the other one.)

How can I do this? Or can I somehow tell docker to start a new container or create a new image with:
1. a base image and with
2. a stack of changes to the file system corresponding to my separate containers?

(Since docker stores the difference of the file system of a container relative to its image (or between different layers?), in principle it should be possible to merge the differences even directly...)

Comment: Why not just define one Dockerfile with the instructions to install whatever you have installed in your two containers?

Comment: +1 Don't use docker images as portable devices. Docker creates them locally to save on downloading and do it's versioning. You should be trying to create and commit a Dockerfile which creates the image you want.